# Column 'tblGender.ID' is not the same data type as referencing column 'tblPerson.GenderID' in foreign key 'tblPerson_GenderID_FK'

Tags: sql, database, debugging, key, relationship

Help I don't know what to do next I tried different things but still showing the same error. As you can see i'm using the same data type the (GenderID and Gender = varchar (15) ) but it shows errors you can find below.

Im using the syntax

```
Alter table ForeignKeyTable add constraint ForeignKeyTable_ForeignKeyColumn_FK
FOREIGN KEY (ForeignKeyColumn) references PrimaryKeyTable (PrimaryKeyColumn)


create table tblPerson (
ID int primary key,
Name varchar (15),
Email varchar (15),
GenderID varchar (15)
)

create table tblGender (
ID int primary key,
Gender varchar (15)
)

select *from tblGender
select *from tblPerson

Alter table tblPerson add constraint tblPerson_GenderID_FK 
FOREIGN KEY (GenderID) references tblGender (ID)
```

THIS IS THE ERROR AFTER EXECUTING

> Msg 1778, Level 16, State 0, Line 18 Column 'tblGender.ID' is not the
>   same data type as referencing column 'tblPerson.GenderID' in foreign
>   key 'tblPerson_GenderID_FK'. Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 18
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: GenderID varchar (15) => should be "int" datatype instead

Answer (score 1):

Update your table creation code with the following:

```
create table tblPerson (
ID int primary key,
Name varchar (15),
Email varchar (15),
GenderID int
)
```

Note: The only change was converting the GenderID from a varchar to an int.